# Shell Script to fetch linux processes and show the process count for individual user as "."

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, process-management

Eg. Processes being run by various users are as below.

```
root 5
xuser 3
yuser 1
```

Then the script should give the output as:

```
root .....
xuser ...
yuser .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash `printf` and `tr` to do this histogram:

```
while read name num; do 
    dots=$(printf "%*s" $num " " | tr " " .)
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$name" "$dots"
done <<END
root 5
xuser 3
yuser 1
END
```

```
root    .....
xuser   ...
yuser   .
```

Comment: This worked. The only issue is the output dots(.) are not in arranged manner vertically.

xrdp .
avahi ..
mssql ..
dd-agent ...
smmsp ...
www-data .....
hadoop ......
postgres ......
ideauser .........
pritam.+ .........
gdm ................

Thanks

Comment: You can pipe to `| column -t` your better alignment

Comment: Thank Glenn. Your suggestions helped me a lot.
My final script which worked perfectly is as below. Please let me know if I can optimise the same.

#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Desktop/p
t=1
while [ $t -lt 6 ]
do
echo "\n"
echo "Occurance $t"
ps axo user:10 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | awk '{print $2,$1}' | while read user process
do
        dots=$(printf "%*s" $process " " | tr " " .)
        printf "%-10s\t%s\n" "$user" "$dots"
done

t=$((t+1))
echo "\n"
sleep 5s
done

Comment: A slightly simpler version for dots generation: `dots=$(printf ".%.0s" $(seq 1 $num))`

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, and assuming that the data is located in `file`:

```
$ perl -ne '/^(\w+)\s+(\d+)$/ && printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, "." x $2)' file
root    .....
xuser   ...
yuser   .
```

You may also apply this on a data stream:

```
somecommand | perl -ne '...as above...'
```

The Perl script matches the initial string and the number in the input, and the outputs the string and the appropriate number of dots, with a tab character in-between.

---

With a bit of tweaking of the above (to be able to read `uniq -c` output, which has the number *first*), the following would get the number of processes running for each user and display the counts as dots:

```
$ ps -ax -o user= | sort | uniq -c | perl -ne '/^\s*(\d+)\s+(\w+)$/ && printf("%-10s%s\n", $2, "." x $1)'
_dbus     .
_dhcp     .
_ntp      ..
_pflogd   .
_slaacd   ..
_smtpd    .....
_smtpq    .
_syslogd  .
_unbound  .
kk        ................
root      ..........................
```

The `ps` command *might* need modification to output the correct thing on Linux (I'm using OpenBSD here, but it seems to do the right thing on Ubuntu too).  The Perl script has changed from the first variation so that it properly reads `uniq -c` output and it formats the lines to allow for usernames of length 10 or less.